# If $X$ and $Y$ are birational then there is a dense open subscheme $U$ of $X$ and a dense open subscheme $V$ of $Y$ such that $U \cong V$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, schemes

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are integral schemes. If $X$ and $Y$ are birational then there is a dense open subscheme $U$ of $X$ and a dense open subscheme $V$ of $Y$ such that $U \cong V$.

My Proof: Since $X$ and $Y$ are birational, we can find dense open subsets $X_1 \subset X$, $Y_1 \subset Y$ and morphisms $F: X_1 \to Y$, $G: Y_1 \to X$ such that $G \circ F|_{F^{-1}(Y_1)} \sim \mathrm{Id}_X$ and $F\circ G|_{G^{-1}(X_1)} \sim \mathrm{Id}_Y$.

By definition of rational map, this means that we can find dense open subsets $U \subset F^{-1}(Y_1) \cap X=F^{-1}(Y_1)$ and $V \subset G^{-1}(X_1) \cap Y=G^{-1}(X_1)$ such that $G\circ F|_U = \mathrm{Id}_U$ and $F \circ G|_V = \mathrm{Id}_V$.

Therefore, $U \cong V$.

---

It seems to me we are done, but I see that some sources (such as the stacks project and Vakil's *FOAG*) have more difficult proofs.

**Is there something wrong with my proof, or something I am missing?**

Comment: What is the definition of birational morphism you are using?

Comment: @LucaMorstabilini A rational map $\pi: X \dashrightarrow Y$ is said to be birational if it is dominant, and there is another rational map (a "rational inverse") $\psi$ that is also dominant, such that $\pi \circ \psi$ is (in the same equivalence class as) the identity on $Y$, and $\psi \circ \pi$ is (in the same equivalence class as) the identity on $X$.